# TypeError: render is not a function...updateContextConsumer

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: render is not a function 
updateContextConsumer 
D:/Portfolio/react-project/context-hooks/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18304

I am tried to solve this, when run the code then it will be show TypeError: render is not a function.
Please help me.
 Here is my 3 files
App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BookList from './context/BookList';
import ThemeContext from './context/ThemeContext'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
       <div className="App">
        <ThemeContext>
          <BookList />
        </ThemeContext>
       </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ThemeContext.js 
when I use `{props.children}` then it will be show the error

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
export const BookContext = createContext();

const ThemeContext = (props) =>  {
 const books = useState([
  {title: 'book1', id: '1'},
  {title: 'book2', id: '2'},
  {title: 'book3', id: '3'},
 ])

 return (
   <BookContext.Provider value={{books}}>
    {props.children}
   </BookContext.Provider>
 )
}

export default ThemeContext;
```

BookList.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { BookContext } from './ThemeContext'

const BookList = () => {
 const { books } = useContext(BookContext);
 console.log(books)
 return (
  <BookContext.Consumer>
   <div className="book-list" >
    <ul className="book-list-area">
     {books.map((books, index) => {
      return <li className="book-list-item" key={index}>{books.title} </li>
     }
     )}
    </ul>
   </div>
  </BookContext.Consumer>
 )
}

export default BookList
```

Comment: Does it give a stack trace or any indication of where the undefined function call is happening?

Comment: Debug in three steps:
1. Comment both <ThemeContext> and <BookList> tags in App.js .
2. Comment only <ThemeContext>
3. Comment only <BookList>. Post here the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is explained in the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

> Requires a function as a child. The function receives the current context value and returns a React node. The value argument passed to the function will be equal to the value prop of the closest Provider for this context above in the tree. If there is no Provider for this context above, the value argument will be equal to the defaultValue that was passed to createContext().

`BookContext.Cosumer` must be

```
<BookContext.Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</BookContext.Consumer>
```

but, you are using `useContext` to access the value, so the `BookContext.Cosumer` is not needed. Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. I have understand where exactly the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just I am not declare proper State variable `const books = useState([`
ThemeContext.js

```
 const ThemeContext = (props) =>  {
 const books = useState([
  {title: 'book1', id: '1'},
  {title: 'book2', id: '2'},
  {title: 'book3', id: '3'},
 ]) <br />
```

Instead of

```
  const ThemeContext = (props) =>  {
  const [books, setBooks] =useState([
  {title: 'book1', id: '1'},
  {title: 'book2', id: '2'},
  {title: 'book3', id: '3'},
 ])
```

BookList.js
and not needed `<BookContext.Consumer>`

```
<BookContext.Consumer>
   <div className="book-list" >
    <ul className="book-list-area">
     {books.map((books, index) => {
      return <li className="book-list-item" key={index}>{books.title} </li>
     }
     )}
    </ul>
   </div>
  </BookContext.Consumer>
```

Instead of

```
   <div className="book-list" >
    <ul className="book-list-area">
     {books.map((books, index) => {
      return <li className="book-list-item" key={index}>{books.title} </li>
     }
     )}
    </ul>
   </div>
```